# Sencha Cmd V3 Beta

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I would like to have an ext app and a touch app within a single workspace. I generated the workspace with:

$ sencha -sdk path/to/ext4.1.1a generate workspace path/toworkspace

This generated: 
workspace/.sencha
workspace/ext

I can then generate an ext app, but not a touch app. 
I have tried to generate the touch app like so:

$ sencha -sdk path/to/touch2.0.1.1 generate app path/totouchapp

I get an error:
"Failed to determine framework name. Please ensure this command was issued from either a framework or application directory"

So, I also tried to generate the touch app by cd'ing to my touch2.0.1.1 sdk, but that did not work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest Cmd tool isn't compatible with older versions of Sencha Touch.  You need to install the latest SDK for it to work, apparently.

Per this [thread in sencha forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?243153-Sencha-Cmd-V3-Beta&p=890144):

> Wrong Touch SDK!

```
I was using the wrong Touch SDK. Found the correct one here:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/announcement.php?f=89
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I just learn the proper way

you have to download the sencha touch SDK (SenchaCmd-3.0.0.250-windows.exe.zip) and install it, and of course you have to download the sencha touch framework (sencha-touch-2.1.0-gpl.zip).

you have to CD (change directory) on the sencha touch framework in my case it is under: `d:\webdav\htdocs\touch` and apply command: sencha generate app gs `d:\webdav\htdocs\gs`

I also try this command: `sencha -sdk D:\webdav\htdocs\touch generate` workspace `D:\webdav\htdocs\gs` and it works.  No more error as the earlier posts.

thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

the name has to be the same thing as it is after the generate such like this

Senchacmd → `sencha -sdk c:\wamp\www\touch2.0.1.1 generate app MyApp c:\wamp\www\MyApp`